# Position WooCommerce basket and pricing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

concerns website 
https://verhalenhuisalbrandswaard.nl/product/de-volharding/

As you can see, the cart and pricing is located below product-image, I would like to have it left of the product. Somehow the theme is positioning all below product.

Any ideas ??

Comment: The problem you write about is related only to CSS, and questions not specific to WordPress are [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Despite this, you have overwritten `float: right` style to `float: none` for `div.summary`. If you change `none` to `right` block with price will be displayed in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which section/ module I can find div.summary

Comment: I do not have this theme, I can not show you where to make changes. Look for the `.entry-summary` or `.summary` class in the CSS files from the theme.